# Why is is wrong to think of probability this way?

Tags: probability

There is a $3$ in $10$ chance a light turns red every second.
When the light is red, there is a $1$ in $4$ chance a bell rings.

Probability would have $3/10 * 1/4 = 3/40 \approx 7.5 \% $ per second that the light is red and the bell rings

So please convince me why it is wrong to think of it this way:

If $3$ in $10$ is $3/10$

and $1$ in $4$ is $1/4$,

Why would the scenario above, a "$1$ in $4$" in a "$3$ in $10$",

not be $1/4$ over $ 3/10$ and thus $\frac{1/4}{3/10}$

turn out to be a $10/12 = 5/6 = 83.33 \%$ per second the light is red and the bell rings.

Why is that bad logic?

Comment: What are the chances that a bell rings when the light is not red?

Comment: In my scenario, there is a zero chance the bell rings if the light is not red.

Comment: But I would be interested to know why it matters and what other ways that would impact things.

Comment: I don't really understand your question, are you asking why ${3 \over 10} { 1 \over 4} \neq {{ 1 \over 4} \over {3 \over 10}  }$?

Comment: I'm asking why you would not apply the same expression between a "3 in 10"  and a "1/4 in 3/10" ?

Comment: You have $P[\text{Ring}] = P[\text{Ring}\mid \text{Red}] \cdot P[ \text{Red}] +P[\text{Ring}\mid \lnot \text{Red}]\cdot P[\lnot \text{Red}] = {1 \over 4} {3 \over 10} + 0$.

Comment: I think you've trapped yourself in semantics. You've decided to express the problem like so: "'1 in 4' in a '3 in 10'". You've also decided that "in" connotes division. But, the "in" in the middle was really just an artifact of how you've decided to word your explanation. Perhaps a better word would be "within". There is a 1 in 4 chance within the 3 in 10 chance. But, ultimately, it doesn't matter how you word it, it matters what operations you do to the numbers, and you did the wrong operation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "a $3$ in $10$ chance a light turns red every second"? What about the seconds when it's already red?

Comment: You have concluded that there is a higher chance that the bell rings and the light is red, than just there is of just the light being red, but whenever the bell rings and the light is red, in particular the light is red, so it happens at least as often that the light is red, than it does that the light is red and the bell is ringing. This is touching on something called the "monotonicity of measure", measure theory is the formal building blocks for probability theory

Answer (score 2):

If you think about what is happening in units and take out the possibility of randomness, perhaps it can help. A 3 in 10 chance of a light turning red basically means for every 10 seconds, there are 3 seconds where a light turns red. I.e., there are 3 red lights every 10 seconds.

The second ratio says when a light is red, $1/4$ times a bell rings. In units, this means for every 4 red lights, we have 1 bell ring.

You want to compute the number of bell rings per second, or $\frac{bells}{seconds}.$ Dimensional analysis would indicate this is
$$\frac{3 \text{ red lights}}{10 \text{ seconds}} \cdot \frac{1 \text{ bell ring}}{4 \text{ red lights}} = \frac{3 \text{ bell rings}}{40 \text{ seconds}}.$$

What you're doing in your question doesn't make sense from a physical, units based perspective.

Comment: Yea the units certainly put it into a perspective.  Thanks!